# When does the grace period start for private parking?

Tags: england-and-wales, appeal, parking

If a parking ticket was purchased 13 minutes after entering a car park, are they eligible to appeal the parking charge for an "invalid parking session"?

If not, then would difficulties such as the following provide a good defense? Difficulties include difficult navigation of car park and difficulty paying i.e machine only takes coins, need to lengthily search for a legitimate site to pay for including the sign-up.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed because "Questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice are off-topic." If you rephrase it more generally it is less likely to be closed.

Comment: @Lag Thanks for the comment, I've took time to rephrase my question and hope it satisfies the site :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a car park covered by the [British Parking Association's Approved Operator Code of Practice](https://www.britishparking.co.uk/code-of-practice-and-compliance-monitoring):

The 'Grace Period' (at least 10 mins) starts at the *end* of the 'parking period' (when the parking period expires).

A 'Consideration Period' (at least 5 mins) starts when the car enters the car park, giving the driver (A) an opportunity to decide whether to park and (B) a few minutes to park.

Comment: *decide whether to park.*... or find a parking spot in the first place.

Comment: Find a parking spot, park, navigate the parking garage on foot to find a ticket machine, buy a ticket and then navigate the parking garage to return to your car.  That could very easily take more than 5 minutes especially as one gets older.

Comment: @User65535 or if the parking lot is big and crowded

Comment: @User65535 for a garage, often you get your ticket of entry right on entry.